# Is non-English string still 'a read-only slice of bytes'?

Tags: go

It's mentioned in https://go.dev/blog/strings that:

***In Go, a string is in effect a read-only slice of bytes.***

To my understanding, `byte` data type is equivalent to `uint8` in Go that represents the ASCII characters which works perfectly with strings that consists of English letters only.

For non-English string, such as Japanese, Korean, Chinese, Arabic etc, is it still correct to say "*In Go, a string is in effect a read-only slice of **`bytes`**.*"?

Or can I say *"In Go, **a non-English** string is in effect a read-only slice of **`Rune`**"* because apparently ASCII does not support the strings with Japanese, Korean, Chinese, Arabic characters which must be represented in Unicode or UTF-8 using `Rune`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To my understanding, byte data type is equivalent to uint8 in Go that represents the ASCII characters which works perfectly with strings that consists of English letters only.

No. Byte doesn't mean ASCII. Go doesn't use ASCII for anything.

Strings in Go are normally UTF-8. The string functions in the standard library all work with UTF-8. Accessing a string as a series of runes using `range` assumes that the string is UTF-8. UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode into bytes. All of this is true regardless of what language you're working with.

Strings can also contain data that *isn't* UTF-8; as the article you quoted said, a string is basically just an immutable `[]byte`, and can contain any sequence of bytes, including binary data, and character data in other encodings than UTF-8. This is perfectly valid; it just doesn't make sense to use `strings` functions or `range` on these "strings". The types really only capture the difference between mutable and immutable; they *don't* capture the difference between "a character string" and "a bunch of bytes".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in this blog https://www.bogotobogo.com/GoLang/GoLang_byte_and_rune.php, it mentions that “ The byte data type represents ASCII characters while the rune data type represents a more broader set of Unicode characters that are encoded in UTF-8 format.”  And now I’m confused.

Comment: Is the “byte” mentioned in "In Go, a string is in effect a read-only slice of bytes." is the “byte” that’s equivalent to uint8? Are we talking about the same “bytes” here? If yes, can I say "In Go, a string is in effect a read-only slice of uint8.” ?

Comment: @ParryWang In Go a byte is unsigned 8-bit integer

Comment: @ParryWang 1. That BogoToBogo tutorial is just plain wrong. 2. Yes, they are the same type, but it's normal to call it `byte` when you're talking about the stuff that files and network sockets and pretty much everything else is made of, and only call it `uint8` if you're interested in doing math on small numbers between 0 and 255 (which is rarely).

Comment: Thanks @hobbs, but if I declare a non-English char variable using single quote such as (var japanese rune = ‘中’ ) this must be presented in rune as it’s 20013 in integer which exceeds the range of uint8 (0-255), I know character and string are two different data types in Go, but it somehow confused me.

Comment: @ParryWang You declared a `rune` variable and it holds a rune. It's not a `byte`, it's not a `[]byte`, and it's not a `string`. It's a `rune`.

Comment: @hobbs, but (var english rune = ‘a’) and (var english byte = ‘a’) are both valid, so English letters “have the advantage” to be both byte and rune, while non-English letters such as Japanese can “only” be declared as rune, and this is very tempting to lead me to think about the difference between ASCII and Unicode, UTF-8 encoding, Thanks anyway for your explanation, if I was born a native English speaker I will not have this question come to my mind and ask it here.

Comment: @ParryWang just a coincidence. Not something you should write (and by the way, it's not about English. 'Ø' and 'ñ' correspond to integers less than 256 too).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `string` will be a slice of bytes regardless of the charset. For example:

```
s := "селёдка"
fmt.Printf("%d\n", len(s))
```

will print `14` even though the word is 7 letters long. That means, you cannot e.g. use `s[2]` to get the third characters.

However, when you're *iterating* over a string, you are getting runes:

```
s := "селёдка"
for _, c := range s {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", c)
}
```

will print the word letter by letter.

If you want to deal with the runes directly, convert the string to the slice:

```
r := []rune(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Is the “byte” mentioned in  "In Go, a string is in effect a read-only slice of bytes." is the “byte” that’s equivalent to uint8? Are we talking about the same “bytes” here? If yes, can I say   "In Go, a string is in effect a read-only slice of uint8.” ?

Comment: @ParryWang yes, `byte` is just an alias for `uint8`.